# Flask Session Variable to WTForms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am running into errors when trying to pass a Flask Session variable to WTForms. I have read everything about the topic through searches and documentation but the correct method is not clear to me. I am completely new to web development and I am sure there are certain concepts that I don't yet understand.

users_department is a Flask session variable that is used for populating a WTForm that lists the project_lead in a wtforms.SelectField. However, I receive a error when calling a Flask session variable, RunTimeError: working outside of request context.

Below is my code.

```
import wtforms
import flask

def get_team_members():
    user_department =  flask.session.get('user_department')
    # run SQLite query to find team members based on the variable user_department
    # create a list from the SQLite results
    return team_results

@app.route('/manage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def manage():
    form = ProjectForm(request.form) #Call the project form to display
    #The line below causes the error but it works if hard coded with a department
    form.project_lead.choices = get_team_members() #Get team members for user
    return render_template('manage.html', form = form)

class ProjectForm(wtforms.Form):
    project_lead = wtforms.SelectField(u'Project Lead',
                                   validators=[wtforms.validators.optional()])
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix it. Do not call a flask session after calling WTforms. Below is the part that needed to change.

```
@app.route('/manage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def manage():
    team = get_team_members() #Get team members for user
    form = ProjectForm(request.form) #Call the project form to display
    form.project_lead.choices = team
    return render_template('manage.html', form = form)
```